# Set an array of the checkbox values with another array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of input checkboxes on a form that look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value=""><span value="Atlanta">Atlanta</span>
<input type="checkbox" value=""><span value="Charleston">Charleston</span>
<input type="checkbox" value=""><span value="Chicago">Chicago</span> and etc.
```

The above is due to running this, `$dataTable.ajax.reload()`, and for some reason this erases the values of the checkboxes in my form.   These checkboxes are not hardcoded and are being dynamically generating.

Instead of doing the below, I realize I can just refresh the page and get all the value back, but I'd like to see if there is another way to do what I'm trying to do below.

Anywho, I took the span text of each checkbox, turned that into an array and called it `spanarr`. I also turned the input checkboxes into an array, called `emergcheck`.

```
var emergspanarr = $('#emergencyForm span').toArray();
var spanarr = [];
var emergcheck = $('#emergencyForm input[type="checkbox"]');

emergspanarr.map(function(item){
    spanarr.push(item.innerHTML.trim());
});
```

I'm trying to insert one span value (from spanarr) into each of input checkbox (from emergcheck).

What I have so far:

```
for (var j = 0; j < emergcheck.length; j++){
    for (var k = 0; k < spanarr.length; k++){
        emergcheck.attr("value", function(i, val){
            return val + spanarr[k];
        })          
    }                   
}
```

But it's producing this:

```
<input value="AtlantaCharlestonChicagoHouston (Sales)Houston (Terminal)Long BeachMarseillesMiamiMontreal....Santa Ana SavannahSeattleSecaucusTorontoVancouverAtlantaCharlestonChicagoHouston (Sales)Houston (Terminal)Long BeachMarseillesMiamiMontrealSanta Ana .....Santa AnaSavannahSeattleSecaucusTorontoVancouver" type="checkbox"><span value="Atlanta">Atlanta</span>

<input value="AtlantaCharlestonChicagoHouston (Sales)Houston (Terminal)Long BeachMarseillesMiamiMontreal....Santa Ana SavannahSeattleSecaucusTorontoVancouverAtlantaCharlestonChicagoHouston (Sales)Houston (Terminal)Long BeachMarseillesMiamiMontrealSanta Ana .....Santa AnaSavannahSeattleSecaucusTorontoVancouver" type="checkbox"><span value="Charleston">Charleston</span> and etc.
```

I want it to be this instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Atlanta"><span value="Atlanta">Atlanta</span>
<input type="checkbox" value="Charleston"><span value="Charleston">Charleston</span>
<input type="checkbox" value="Chicago"><span value="Chicago">Chicago</span
```

I feel like I am close.  What am I missing? In need of another pair of eyes.  Thanks,

Comment: Please include code as code, not as an image. You should be able to copy and paste from the Elements panel (or right-click and select Copy > Copy outerHTML).

Comment: FYI, `map` returns an array; there's no need to `push`. `var spanarr = emergspanarr.map(function (item) { return item.innerHTML.trim(); })`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey after copying the outerHTML, I realized the loop was worse than I originally thought (lol, outputs the array 17 times within value ) so I shortened the output for post.  Duly noted on the push, I'll change that in my code.  Thanks!

Comment: Try my answer @hnewbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to change code with below code -

JS Code -

```
for (var j = 0; j < emergcheck.length; j++){
    emergcheck.eq(j).val(spanarr[j]);                
}
```

Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Could you explain what is happening here?  It worked!  I've never seen eq() used before.  Looked it up @ the jquery site.   Was it because my indexes for both arrays needed to be filtered?

Comment: It just used to select `tags` with their index value you can read it more from here [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer as well for upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want the [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript) of the input. You can use `.val()` from jQuery or just `.value` as pure js.

jQuery way:

```
var emergspanarr = $('#emergencyForm span').toArray();
var emergcheck = $('#emergencyForm input[type="checkbox"]').toArray();

for (var j = 0; j < emergcheck.length; j++) {
    emergcheck[j].val(emergspanarr[j].val());
}
```

Pure js way:

```
var emergspanarr = $('#emergencyForm span').toArray();
var emergcheck = $('#emergencyForm input[type="checkbox"]').toArray();

for (var j = 0; j < emergcheck.length; j++){
    emergcheck[j].value = emergspanarr[j].value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but neither strangely works.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: @hnewbie I didn't realize your spanarr held innerHTML. This would only work with an array of elements. My bad. I'll edit my answer to use emergspanarr instead. That should work

Comment: The "Pure js way" uses jQuery too (for selecting the elements). If you want pure JS for that, use `var emergspanarr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#emergencyForm span'));` and similar code for the other one.